# Any ideas why this simple code isnt working?

Tags: php

Does anyone know why this simple bit of code wont work? The second loop doesnt seem to take place.

```
while(list($get_key, $get_value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS)) {
    if (!${$get_key}) {
         ${$get_key}=$get_value; 
    }
}

while(list($keyone, $valueone) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS))    
{
    echo $keyone;
}
```

Comment: `$HTTP_GET_VARS`? why?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: The second WHILE apparently never evaluates to TRUE. Instead of "=" it should be "==" to compare, not assign.

Comment: First question here guys, so apologies for not knowing the etiquette.

Comment: So the first loop is used to define get variables for the script, because a variety of them will be used and global_register is off, I needed to use this.

Comment: Second is used to carry out an action, based on all those variables, in example its just an echo test, but it doesnt seem to run.

Comment: Changing '=' to '==' results in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting '=' in variables.php on line 16

Comment: Yeah I just discovered that too. But I still think it never evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is the use of `each()`. It remembers the index it has reached in the array so in your second loop there is nothing left to loop out so it evaluates to false. If you use `reset()` this should resolve the issue.

```
while(list($get_key, $get_value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS)) {
  if (!${$get_key}) {
     ${$get_key}=$get_value; 
  }
}

reset($HTTP_GET_VARS);//will put the pointer back to the first element

while(list($keyone, $valueone) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS))    
{
  echo $keyone;
}
```

Alternatively you can just use the `foreach(){}` syntax which will always start from the first element in the array.